# adding new peer | 'chaincode with name 'cc' already exists' on composer network start

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am facing issues while while starting chaincode on my newly added peer in hyperledger network. Let me explain you the issue I am facing.

I had up and running hyperledger network where I had installed my bna with version 0.0.1. When I ping my network everything works fine. I have added new peer in network without bringing network down. Now I am trying to install bna on newly added peer. I have added new peer in connection profile for both organizations after adding I have created card and installed on organization where I have added new peer. bna is installed on the peer successfully. Now I am trying to start the network with `composer network start`. this is the point where I am receiving the following error.

```
Processing these Network Admins:
        userName: user1
        userName: user2

× Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: chaincode with name 'cc' already exists
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: chaincode with name 'cc' already exists
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: chaincode with name 'cc' already exists
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: chaincode with name 'cc' already exists
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: chaincode with name 'cc' already exists
Command failed
```

Please help in this matter. How am I suppose to add bna on newly added peer in network. I dont want bring my network down while adding new peer and install bna file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the bna is the same on the other peers, then you don't need to do anything else. All you need to do is install it onto the peer (the install command will not install it on peers that already have the bna, but will install it on peers that don't have it), and it sounds like you have done the correct approach by updating your connection profile and run the install command using an identity that is in the same MSP as your new Peer.
You do not need to start the business network because it is already started and that is the meaning of the error you are getting.
Now if you submit a transaction it will be sent to all peers in your connection profile. For your new Peer it will bring up the chaincode (ie the business network) automatically so that it can simulate that submission.

Comment: @david_k when after all these steps, I update the JSON profile and create the new cards with the updated connection profiles. But when I try to use these new cards I get the following error: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: transaction returned with failure: Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier 'XYZ', has not been registered -- Even when I try to ping the network